# How can I make an instance a singleton in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my service provider, I manually construct a service. I want to bind it into the container as a singleton. However, when I do:

```
$this->app->singleton('React\EventLoop\LoopInterface', $loop);
```

The `singleton()` method gets the class of `$loop` and attempts to create the object itself, which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to work, you'll need to pass a closure as the second argument to **singleton** method. If you $loop object already exists before register method is called, just do:

```
$loop = ...; // $loop is instantiated somewhere before this code
$this->app->singleton('React\EventLoop\LoopInterface', function() use ($loop) {
  return $loop;
});
```

or, if it's ok to instantiate $loop here, it's even better to do:

```
$this->app->singleton('React\EventLoop\LoopInterface', function() {
  $loop = ...; //instantiate $loop
  return $loop;
});
```